# How do I get the original sender from a forwarded email using Rails 3 mail gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I am trying to forward email into my Rails3/Ruby 1.9.2 app and I need to get the sender's email address.

Anyone know how to do this with new Rails 3 mail?

Also can I get the time received or sent from the sender?

Comment: Please explain the full flow.

Comment: @Roman   so rob sends and email to jane and jane forwards the email to the rails3 app dropbox.    i want to get robs emails address and name.   any ideas ?

Comment: It really depends on the flow, and what "forwards" really means in this context.

Comment: I think what rick is asking is how to see if the mail server forwards the message on. If intact your talking about seeing who the original humans that have sent on the message are then there is no reliable way to do this. Mail clients are all quite different and it's unlikely you could achieve this reliably. Sometimes the original message id can be passed on but that doesn't help unless the first persons message is tracked by you too

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail#reading-an-email)

You should just be able to call

```
mail.envelope_from
```

Comment: If it was forwarded, then the enveloper.from will be the address of the forwarding agent.

Comment: thanks guys but i want to get the address from for the sender not the person who forwarded it.   any ideas ?

Comment: @rick this is not a rails issue. Basically that information is not available. Well it sometimes is part of the message in the forward, but you cannot reliably get that information. There may be a header for an id of the original message if it's in your system to look it up however this directly depends on the sender's email client.

Comment: don't know if it changed or was wrong in the first place:

it needs to be: mail.envelope_from

Answer (score 0):

Normally the forwarding mail server will pass on the address it's forwarding for as a header. At CloudMailin we are experimenting with passing the header x-forwarded-for which google and some other servers add. It's not garaunteed but if your server sets a header and your only using one it will be consistent so you can rely on it being there.

Comment: Also time sent from the sender should be in a header as sent. If that fails you can try the first hop of the received from headers.